# awk equivalent of str_replace

Tags: bash, awk

Is there a function in awk that replaces one string with another? Example, we have e file with values like this:

```
data_file:
/some/path/to/data/2014/01-02/some_file
/some/path/to/data/2014/01-02/some_file2
/some/path/to/data/2014/01-02/some_file3

cat data_file | awk '{ str_replace("/some/path/to/data/", ""); print }'
# the above should output
2014/01-02/some_file
2014/01-02/some_file2
2014/01-02/some_file3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `cut` is more appropriate in this context:

```
$ cut -d/ -f6- inputfile
2014/01-02/some_file
2014/01-02/some_file2
2014/01-02/some_file3
```

Use [`sub()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for `awk`:

```
$ awk '{sub("/some/path/to/data/", "", $0)}1' inputfile
2014/01-02/some_file
2014/01-02/some_file2
2014/01-02/some_file3
```

Comment: You can remove the `$0` from `awk`, since its default data if omitted.

Comment: @Jotne Yup, [golfing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) is becoming popular anyways!

Comment: Doesn't work for the general case. If the replacement string contains `&`, this repeats the found string.

Answer (score 5):

No. There's `[g]sub()` to replace a regular expression with a string, but to replace a string with a string you need a combination of index(), length(), and substr():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{old="/some/path/to/data/"; new=""}
  idx=index($0,old){$0 = substr($0,1,idx-1) new substr($0,idx+length(old))} 1' file
2014/01-02/some_file
2014/01-02/some_file2
2014/01-02/some_file3
```

The difference between using this approach and using [g]sub() would become clear if you had any RE metacharacters in your search string, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
/some/.*/2014/01-02/some_file
/some/.*/2014/01-02/some_file2
/some/.*/2014/01-02/some_file3

$ awk '{sub("/some/.*/","")}1' file
some_file
some_file2
some_file3

$ awk 'BEGIN{old="/some/.*/"; new=""}
  idx=index($0,old){ $0 = substr($0,1,idx-1) new substr($0,idx+length(old))} 1' file
2014/01-02/some_file
2014/01-02/some_file2
2014/01-02/some_file3
```

Answer (score 1):

Some like this:

```
awk '{sub(/.*data/,"")}8' file
/2014/01-02/some_file
/2014/01-02/some_file2
/2014/01-02/some_file3
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the `8` at the end?

Comment: @RolandIllig It just a random number.  Any number will be a true state and any true stat without action would do default action, in this case, print the line, so this could be change to: `awk '{sub(/.*data/,"")} {print $0}' file`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I always thought that the random number were 4, didn't notice that it doubled in the meantime.

Comment: `I always thought that the random number were 4`. Sony approves :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  I would have used 42, but can not be multiple digits :)